# Restricted range MLE of normal distribution where the mean must be nonnegative

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Source of the question: the Example 7.2.8 of Statistical Inference Book by Casella and Berger.

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid $n(\theta,1)$, where it is known that $\theta$ must be nonnegative. With no restrictions on $\theta$, we saw that the MLE of $\theta$ is $\bar{X}$; however, if $\bar{X}$ is negative, it will be outside the range of the parameter.

I don't understand the below and I need help. How to get the MLE of $\theta$ in normal distribution when $\theta$ is known nonnegative?

> If $\bar{x}$ is negative, it is easy to check that the likelihood
> function $L(\theta|x)$ is decreasing in $\theta$ for $\theta \geq 0$
> and is maximized at $\hat{\theta}=0$. Hence, in this case, the MLE of
> $\theta$ is
>
> $$\hat{\theta}=  \bar{X} \text{   if   } \bar{X} \geq 0 \text{   and  
> > } \hat{\theta}=0  \text{   if   } \bar{X} < 0.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you're trying to maximize the likelihood function $L(\theta, x)$.

Which is defined as:
$$L(\theta, x) = \prod f_\theta(x_i)$$
Where $f_\theta$ is the density function of $\mathcal{N}(\theta, 1)$. However, most of the time, we prefer to maximize the logarithm of the likelihood function, as it is just so much more convenient.
$$l(\theta, x) = \log L (\theta, x)=\sum \log f_\theta(x_i)$$
The big advantage about this log likelihood function is that has a close relationship with the likelihood function: a lower/higher log-likelihood implies a lower/higher likelihood and vice verse. So we can just focus on this log likelihood. Working out the math, we find (while leaving out some

$$l(\theta, x) = -n\log (\sqrt{2\pi}) + \sum -0.5 (x_i - \theta)^2$$

If we try to optimize it, we can just take the derivative of this function w.r.t. $\theta$ to find:
$$l'(\theta, x) = - n\cdot \theta + \sum x_i$$

Which is zero if $\theta = \overline x$, therefore this is the optimizer. However, the big question is, how do we maximize the log-likelihood function under the constraint that $\theta \geq 0$?

Basically one way to see this is by defining that $l(\theta, x) = -\infty$ if $\theta < 0$: it cannot happen, so there is absolutely no likelihood attributed to it. So the next question will be: for which value for $\theta \geq 0$ does $l$ give the highest score?

As you can see, if $\overline x < 0$ and $\theta \geq 0$, the derivative $l'$ becomes smaller than 0. In other words, $l$ is strictly decreasing. So if $\overline x < 0$, then $\theta = 0$ will always have a higher log-likelihood than any $\theta > 0$.

Hence the conclusion you can draw is that the maximum likelihood estimator under the constraints posed is $\theta = \overline x$ if $\overline x > 0$, and $\theta = 0$ else.

Comment: Whoops, yeah I meant maximize

Comment: Ah I meant $\overline x < 0$, does that help clarify the steps?